# How to rotate a parent element to display rotated child elements in 3D space

Tags: css, 3d, rotation, transform, css-transforms

I am creating an application that allows a developer to rotate elements in 2D and 3D space, via data attributes. The following rotates step 2 90 degrees on the X axis:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="canvas">
    <div class="step">
      Step 1
    </div>
    <div class="step" data-rotate-x="90">
      Step 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

One step is shown at a time. The application will rotate the canvas to show each step. To do this, I am taking each step's rotations and reversing them, so when step 2 is navigated to, the canvas is given the following:

```
<div id="canvas" style="transform: rotateX(-90deg);">
```

The problem I am having is calculating the necessary rotations when more than one rotation is applied to a step.

**Demo 1**: http://jsbin.com/zafek/1/edit - shows the application working with a rotation on the X axis applied to step 2.

**Demo 2**: http://jsbin.com/rices/2/edit - applies both an X and Y on step 2, but as you will see, it incorrectly rotates the canvas.

Can anyone assist with the mathematics involved please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the rotations is important, as each rotation changes the axes for the next rotation.

In demo 2, it looks like you should be rotating Y before X:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is indeed to reverse all of the transforms:

    -webkit-transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateY(-90deg) rotateX(-90deg);